# Solspace User: notify admin of signup

Tags: solspace, solspace-user

Is it possible? Have a second reg form with User that goes to a specific group as opposed to main site signup. Is it possible to specify on this reg form alone that an Admin gets a mail on new signups?

Comment: Sorry, there isn't a way "out-of-the-box" to do this with User.

Comment: Thanks... I thought as much. How to people do it usually? Is MX Notify compatible?

Comment: Posted an answer about this not being possible with User, and mentioned the native EE admin notification settings that is available (but not flexible enough for your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with User.  I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category: http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

The only option for notifying to a specific email address when a registration is completed is through EE's native settings under *Member => Preferences => Notification Preferences*:
"**Send new member notifications?**" and "**Email Address for Notification**". However, this is of course not specific per-registration form.